# How is $example different from example(%rip)?

Tags: assembly, att

I've spent 2 hours googling, but to no avail --- there are not many beginner-level guides for assembly, and the course I am taking right now dos not do a very good job at explaining some stuff.

Anyway; I've been trying to work with SSE and tried comparing two `double`s using `comisd` instruction. I've spent a lot of time to understand how to hard-code a non-integer constant (let's call it `example`, it is declared as

```
example:
    .long   3794832442
    .long   1044740494
```

); but after I've done that, I couldn't get it to work --- "operand type mismatch". I've turned to C-to-assembly translator and found out that instead of my `comisd  $example, %xmm0` it used `comisd example(%rip), %xmm0`, and it turned out to work. Now I don't understand, how does it work and how are these different?

Comment: `$` is an immediate, that can't work. `comisd example, %xmm0` would have worked.

Comment: theoretically `example equ ((1044740494<<32)+3794832442)` would be correct thing for `$example`, but there's no `comisd` instruction taking `imm64` argument, only `xmm/m64` are valid, so your definition is correct (value stored in memory and symbol `example` is label pointing to it's address), and the usage in instruction needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$example` is simply the absolute address of that variable - it doesn't mean a memory access.

You get the "operand type mismatch" because `comisd` does not support an immediate operand. `comisd example, %xmm0` (without the `$`) would have worked, as that is a memory reference.

`example(%rip)` is using the PC-relative addressing mode introduced in x86-64, which makes the code position-independent because instead of using an absolute address, it uses an offset from the current instruction pointer.

---

<sub>Based on an answer of Jonathon Reinhart.</sub>